# If a DRAM entity has a 12 bit address input and 16 bits of data input/output, is each address refering to one bit, or one 16 bit word?

Tags: memory-address

I have a diagram that has the address bus into the DRAM entity as 12 bits, and the data input/output as 16 bits.

-This means its a "2^12 * 16" memory?

-This is where I get confused, my textbook shows a bit level organization of a a 16 bit DRAM, where the first 2 bits of the 4 bit address represent the row, and the last 2 bits the column.

-In that textbook example each address is referring to one bit, so in the diagram described above if I were to arrange the DRAM bits into a square matrix it would have 2^6 rows addressable, and 2^6 columns addressable, correct?

-Now, does each column address refer to 1 bit, or does each column address refer to 1, 16 bit word?

-Example, if I gave memory address "000001000011" into the entity in the diagram, the row the data is located would be the "000001" row, and the the "000011" column would hold my data? And this column is referring to 1 bit or 1, 16 bit word?

Comment: What textbook are you looking at?